# Java - GridLayout resize JPanel

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm trying to resize the height of each JPanel inside another JPanel which has a GridLayout.

This is what I have so far:

```
JPanel store = new JPanel();
store.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 0));

JPanel computerPanel = new JPanel();
computerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Computers"));
computerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 30));

JPanel cablesPanel = new JPanel();
cablesPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Cables"));

JPanel accessoriesPanel = new JPanel();
accessoriesPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Accessories"));

JPanel repairPanel = new JPanel();
repairPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Repair"));

store.add(computerPanel);
store.add(cablesPanel);
store.add(accessoriesPanel);
store.add(repairPanel);

JPanel view = new JPanel();
view.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
view.add(store, BorderLayout.CENTER);

add(view);
```

This is what the GUI outputs: 
[image: Screen shot]

I want to resize each JPanel (computerPanel, cablelPanel, accessoriesPanel, repairPanel) inside the JPanel store.

I have tried:

`computerPanel.setPrefferedSize()` but that doesn't work...

Comment: Does it have to be a `GridLayout`?  `GridLayout` forces everything to be the same size, which is not what you want. Would `FlowLayout` work for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to resize each JPanel, you're not using the appropriate LayoutManager. GridLayout (which you're using now) specifically does not allow such resizing, instead fixing each cell to the exact same size.

Consider using a different LayoutManager, such as BoxLayout or GridBagLayout.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#gridbag) to figure out which LayoutManager is most appropriate for your needs.